# Ionic Zip password set in azure blob storage and set best compression for zip folder not files

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, ionic-zip

How to set zip folder best compression and set a password for Zip folder, I have few Code that i am used please help me how to set best compression and password for zip folder.

```
using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())                    
{ 
zipFile.Save(zipStream);
zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                        
CloudBlockBlob cblob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MockTestZip/MT-" + this.mockExamId + ".zip");
cblob.UploadFromStream(zipStream);                        
}
```

I just added these two lines in it but password is not set in zip folder in azure blob storage

```
zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
zipFile.Password = "encrypt";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I leverage [DotNetZip version 1.10.1](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) to test this issue on my side. And here is the remark about the `Password` property in `ZipFile`:

> When writing a zip archive, **this password is applied to the entries, not to the zip archive itself**. It applies to any ZipEntry subsequently added to the ZipFile,
>   using one of the AddFile, AddDirectory, AddEntry, or AddItem methods, etc.

Based on your scenario, I assumed that you could store the files in a zip file without password, and then store the zip file within a second outer zip file with password as follows:

```
using (ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile())
{
    zipFile.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;
    zipFile.Password = "{your-password}";
    zipFile.AddFile(@"inner.zip",""); //Passing the empty string ("") to store your zip file at the root path within the archive.
    using (var zipStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        zipFile.Save(zipStream);
        zipStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        CloudBlockBlob cblob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("MockTestZip/MT-" + this.mockExamId + ".zip");
        cblob.UploadFromStream(zipStream);
    }
}
```